# Junit test, NoSuchElementException by Scanner

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I had one main method and i need test it. I had two test methods, if I start them separately - all worked. But if I start test all class - got error on second method.

Main method:

```
public boolean run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(message);
            String answer = SCANNER.nextLine();
            if (isTrue(answer)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (isFalse(answer)) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("Cant read your answer, try again");
        }
        throw new UncheckedIOException(
                new IOException("Cant read your answer more then 3 times, program close"));
    }
```

My test methods, I need to simulate a scanner:

```
@Test
    void runTrueAnswerTest() {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("yes".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
       CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
        assertTrue(cliSimpleAskView.run());
        System.setIn(System.in);

    }

    @Test
    void runFalseAnswerTest()  {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("no".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
        assertFalse(cliSimpleAskView.run());
        System.setIn(System.in);
    }
```

Error that i have:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
```

Whats goin wrong?

Comment: How do you initialize the SCANNER object?

Comment: public class CliSimpleAskView {
    private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Ohh, when I disable "static" its all wokr! thank you!!! @javadev